# Octave regex to split a char string in substrings

Tags: regex, substring, octave

Somebody can help me to split "12345678" into "1234" and "56" and "78"?

I have tried `regexp("12345678",'\d{4};\d{2};\d{2}','split')` but this returns the complete string.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [regex documentation](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/regexp.html), I think you could create tokens using capturing groups.

```
regexp("12345678",'(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})','tokens')
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lH3pNm/1)

Comment: This function as whished... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

For 'split' you should give the separator as regex.

```
octave> regexp( 'aaa, bb;Ccc ccC  ;ddd', '\s*[,;]\s*', 'split' )
ans =
{
  [1,1] = aaa
  [1,2] = bb
  [1,3] = Ccc ccC
  [1,4] = ddd
}
```